# NavigationLink crashing when upcoming NavigationDestination references Core Data

Tags: swiftui, core-data, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm building the outline for a SwiftUI app that uses Core Data, using NavigationStack and NavigationLink. I am putting in placeholder views for the time being that don't use any data. However, I am running into the following problem:

Initial View --> Placeholder A - *NavigationLink fails* -> Placeholder B --> View that uses the results of a Core Data fetch request in its parameters.

The NavigationDestination in the B view has the destination FinalView(parameter: CoreDataResults), and it looks like this is the problem. A simpler version of the code that still generates the error follows.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestCrashAppApp: App {
    @StateObject private var dataController: DataController = DataController()
    @StateObject var navigationHandler = NavigationHandler()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
                .environmentObject(navigationHandler)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var pathManager: NavigationHandler
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var results: FetchedResults<MyEntity>
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink("Test Link", value: 1)
            }
            .padding()
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { int in
                SecondView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var results: FetchedResults<MyEntity>
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("Test Other Link", value: "")
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { str in
                Text("\(results[0].property)")
            }
    }
}

class DataController: ObservableObject {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TestModel")
    
    init() {
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Core Data failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            self.container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
        }
    }
}

class NavigationHandler: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()
    
    func reset() {
        path = NavigationPath()
    }
    
    func goBack() {
        path.removeLast(1)
    }
}
```

TestModel contains one entity, MyEntity, with a single attribute property (Int16).

The exact problem is unclear - when clicking on the NavigationLink, the screen freezes, memory usage steadily increases, and the CPU jumps to 99%. However, I have narrowed it down to the NavigationDestination. When removing the results[0].property in SecondView and replacing it with a general text view, it functions as expected. I've also tried to move the destination-containing-core-data-parameter into the initial view, to see if it crashes then. This doesn't do anything, and it instead works correctly.

Would anybody know how this error can be resolved? Thanks!

Comment: You assume the results are loaded at all times including the very first frame. You should pass the object itself. You have to account for an empty sequence

Comment: @loremipsum That makes sense, but how exactly would I do that?

Comment: instead of `String.self` use `MyEntity.self` and use `results` to get the `value` for the link